# Staic analysis gives "Dereferencing <storage from new>, which is known to be nullptr"

Tags: c++, static-analysis, coverity

I was running static analysis using Coverity on a project, while I ran into this error being reported by the tool:

```
Dereferencing <storage from new>, which is known to be nullptr
```

The code snippet is:

```
typedef struct envelope
{
      char *message;
      void *context;
      bool response;
}envelopeRef;

int main()
{
   /* here coverity tells that
      1. returned_null: operator new returns nullptr (checked 46 out of 52 times)
      2. var_assigned: Assigning: <storage from new> = nullptr return value from operator new
      3. dereference: Dereferencing <storage from new>, which is known to be nullptr.
   */
    envelopeRef *h = new (std::nothrow)envelopeRef();
    if(nullptr != h)
    {
       //do something
       delete h;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Looks like a false positive to me.  What happens if you change the syntactic form of the check of `h`?  I would try `if (h != nullptr)`, `if (0 != h)`, and `if (h)` for starters.  If any of these behave differently then that would confirm it is a bug in Coverity.  (Also, are there really two events numbered "2"?)

Comment: event number is 3. sorry..

Comment: do you get the same error if you add a nothrowing constructor? e.g. struct envelopeRef
{
 envelopeRef() noexcept : message(nullptr), context(nullptr), response(false) 
 {}
 
    char *message;
    void *context;
    bool response;
};